# User selected values from JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

When a user fills out a form in a mobile application a json is created. I load this json into a postgres database and wanting to pull is apart and select the inputs that the user has selected.

I find this hard to explain you really need to see the json and the expected results. The json looks like this...

```
{
   "iso_created_at":"2019-06-25T14:50:59+10:00",
   "form_fields":[
      {
         "field_type":"DateAndTime",
         "mandatory":false,
         "form_order":0,
         "editable":true,
         "visibility":"public",
         "label":"Time & Date Select",
         "value":"2019-06-25T14:50:00+10:00",
         "key":"f_10139_64_14",
         "field_visibility":"public",
         "data":{
            "default_to_current":true
         },
         "id":89066
      },
      {
         "field_type":"Image",
         "mandatory":false,
         "form_order":6,
         "editable":true,
         "visibility":"public",
         "label":"Photos",
         "value":[

         ],
         "key":"f_10139_1_8",
         "field_visibility":"public",
         "data":{

         },
         "id":67682
      },
      {
         "field_type":"DropDown",
         "mandatory":true,
         "form_order":2,
         "editable":true,
         "visibility":"public",
         "label":"Customer ID",
         "value":"f_10139_35_13_35_1",
         "key":"f_10139_35_13",
         "field_visibility":"public",
         "data":{
            "options":[
               {
                  "is_default":false,
                  "display_order":0,
                  "enabled":true,
                  "value":"f_10139_35_13_35_1",
                  "label":"27"
               }
            ],
            "multi_select":false
         },
         "id":86039
      },
      {
         "field_type":"CheckBox",
         "mandatory":true,
         "form_order":3,
         "editable":true,
         "visibility":"public",
         "label":"Measure",
         "value":[
            "f_7422_10_7_10_1",
            "f_7422_10_7_10_2"
         ],
         "key":"f_10139_1_5",
         "field_visibility":"public",
         "data":{
            "options":[
               {
                  "is_default":true,
                  "display_order":0,
                  "enabled":true,
                  "value":"f_7422_10_7_10_1",
                  "label":"Kg"
               },
               {
                  "is_default":true,
                  "display_order":0,
                  "enabled":true,
                  "value":"f_7422_10_7_10_2",
                  "label":"Mm"
               }
            ],
            "multi_select":true
         },
         "id":67679
      },
      {
         "field_type":"ShortTextBox",
         "mandatory":true,
         "form_order":4,
         "editable":true,
         "visibility":"public",
         "label":"Qty",
         "value":"1000",
         "key":"f_10139_9_9",
         "field_visibility":"public",
         "data":{

         },
         "id":85776
      }
   ],
   "address":"Latitude: -37.811812 Longitude: 144.971745",
   "shape_id":6456,
   "category_id":75673,
   "id":345,
   "account_id":778
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Expected results:

```
account_id | report_id | field_label        | field_value
------------------------------------------------------------------------
778        | 345       | Time & Date Select | 2019-06-25T14:50:00+10:00
778        | 345       | Photos             |  []
778        | 345       | Customer ID        | 27
778        | 345       | Measure            | Kg 
778        | 345       | Measure            | Mm
778        | 345       | Qty                | 1000
```

Comment: Are the five fields always the same five fields? Because the structure of each of them is wildly inconsistent, one might need to hardcode each field separately instead of making a clever loop. And what do you want to happen when `Photos` is not empty?

Comment: Yes always the same five fields. If photos is not empty then I want to show whatever the user has put there this will be a url

Answer (score 1):

like say @Amadan, might need to hardcode each field separately instead of making a clever loop ,especially with the fields "Customer ID" "and" "Measure" or any other that requires it.

You can use the json function: json_array_elements_text, here you have a example, you can adjust to your case, i am trying with your case:

```
select account_id::text,report_id::text,field_label::text,
--case ""Customer ID"" and ""Measure""
case
when field_label::text='"Customer ID"' then  ((todo->'data'->'options')->0->'label')::text
when field_label::text='"Measure"' then  ((todo->'data'->'options')->0->'label')::text ||',' ||((todo->'data'->'options')->1->'label')::text

else 
field_value::text
end as field_value
from 
(
select dato->'account_id' as account_id,dato->'id' as report_id, 
(json_array_elements_text(dato->'form_fields')::json)->'label' as field_label,
(json_array_elements_text(dato->'form_fields')::json)->'value' as field_value,
(json_array_elements_text(dato->'form_fields')::json) as todo
from (
select '{"iso_created_at": "2019-06-25T14:50:59+10:00",  "form_fields": [
{"field_type": "DateAndTime", "mandatory": false, "form_order": 0, "editable": true, "visibility": "public", "label": "Time & Date Select", "value": "2019-06-25T14:50:00+10:00", "key": "f_10139_64_14", "field_visibility": "public", "data": 
 {"default_to_current": true}, "id": 89066},

 {"field_type": "Image", "mandatory": false, "form_order": 6, "editable": true, "visibility": "public", "label": "Photos", "value": [], "key": "f_10139_1_8", "field_visibility": "public", "data": {}, "id": 67682},

  {"field_type": "DropDown", "mandatory": true, "form_order": 2, "editable": true, "visibility": "public", "label": "Customer ID", "value": "f_10139_35_13_35_1", "key": "f_10139_35_13", "field_visibility": "public", "data": {"options": [{"is_default": false, "display_order": 0, "enabled": true, "value": "f_10139_35_13_35_1", "label": "27"}], "multi_select": false}, "id": 86039},

 {"field_type": "CheckBox", "mandatory": true, "form_order": 3, "editable": true, "visibility": "public", "label": "Measure", "value": ["f_7422_10_7_10_1","f_7422_10_7_10_2"], "key": "f_10139_1_5", "field_visibility": "public", "data": {"options": [{"is_default": true, "display_order": 0, "enabled": true, "value": "f_7422_10_7_10_1", "label": "Kg"},{"is_default": true, "display_order": 0, "enabled": true, "value": "f_7422_10_7_10_2", "label": "Mm"}], "multi_select": true}, "id": 67679},

 {"field_type": "ShortTextBox", "mandatory": true, "form_order": 4, "editable": true, "visibility": "public", "label": "Qty", "value": "1000", "key": "f_10139_9_9", "field_visibility": "public", "data": {}, "id": 85776}

 ], "address": "Latitude: -37.811812 Longitude: 144.971745", "shape_id": 6456, "category_id": 75673, "id": 345, "account_id": 778}'::json as dato) as dat
 ) dat2
```

and i get this result, similar to you: 
   [image]

take this example and ajust to you

regards

Comment: Close but not what I'm after if the user only selects on value in the 'Measure' field your code will not work. If they just select Kg I still get Kg, Mm Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You need to unnest the values in `form_fields` and then pick the label and the value from that JSON object:

```
select fd.account_id, 
       fd.report_id, 
       ff.field ->> 'label' as field_label,
       ff.field ->> 'value' as field_value
from form_data fd
  left join jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'form_fields') as ff(field) on true;
```

The left join is needed to still see the row from `form_data` even if no `form_fields` is available in the main JSON column.

The above assumes a table `form_data` with the columns `account_id`, `report_id` and `data` (which contains the JSON)
Online example: https://rextester.com/RNIBSB94484